# NPE when calling a mocked object (Mockito)

Tags: mocking, mockito

I'm having problems calling a mocked method of an object that is returned by another mocked method of my mocked service.

In particular I want to mock the result of "builder.get()". But when "builder.get()" is called, I'm gettting a null pointer exception (builder is null).

My Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

@Autowired
MyClientService myClientService;

@RequestMapping("/myMethod")
@Validated
public MyCustomResponse myMethod(@RequestParam String someId, @Valid @ModelAttribute("someParams") SomeHeaderParams someHeaderParams) {
    final String targetString = myClientService.buildTargetString("resource", someId + "/myMethod");
    final Map<String, String> headerMap = myClientService.getHeaderParams(someHeaderParams);

    Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramsMap.put("SOME_ID", someId);

    Invocation.Builder builder = myClientService.buildRequest(targetString, headerMap, paramsMap);
    final Response response = builder.get();
    return response.readEntity(MyCustomResponse.class);
}
```

}

And my Test looks like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTests {

@Spy
@InjectMocks
MyController myControllerController;

@Mock
MyClientService myClientService;

SomeHeaderParams someHeaderParams;

@Before
public void init() {
    someHeaderParams = new SomeHeaderParams();
    someHeaderParams.setCommunicationLanguage("de");
    someHeaderParams.setCrId("123");
    someHeaderParams.setMemberUserId("qwe");
}

@Test

public void myTest() {
    MyCustomResponse myResponseMock = mock(MyCustomResponse.class);
    Response responseMock = mock(Response.class);
    Mockito.when(responseMock.readEntity(MyCustomResponse.class)).thenReturn(myResponseMock);

    Invocation.Builder builderMock = mock(Invocation.Builder.class);
    Mockito.when(builderMock.get()).thenReturn(responseMock);
    Mockito.when(myClientService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);
    MyCustomResponse response = myControllerController.myMethod("myBusinessId", someHeaderParams);
}
```

}
This should not be too difficult but I didn't find any examples where the mocked method returned another Mock, I only found examples where it returns a String.

Comment: One question: in your test, is the line 
`Mockito.when(auskunftClientService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);`

supposed to be 

`Mockito.when(someService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);`

?

Comment: yep, changed it, thank you

Comment: **1** Where are you getting the NPE? **2** I don't see anywhere in the code `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` to initialise your mocks; are you using a different runner such as [MockitoJUnitRunner](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html)? **3** You can [configure a mock to return a whole hierarchy of mocks/stubs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Answers.html) instead of defaults (null, false, 0, etc). This allows mock configuration (even intermediate ones) bypassing the need to create intermediary mocks yourself

Comment: You can now see the complete class with the annotationsI use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second row of `myMethod(String someId, SomeHeaderParams someHeaderParams)` in `MyController` class:

There is an invocation of the method `myClientService.getHeaderParams(SomeHeaderParams)`: I don't see any mock configuration for that invocation, so it should return `null`, and when the `buildRequest(String, Map, Map)` method is called, it should recive a `null` as second argument. The matcher `anyMap()` is not met, and this is why it returns the default value, `null`, instead of the configured mock for the `Invocation.Builder` class.

The solution can be to include the following in your test:

```
Mockito.when(myClientService.getHeaderParams(Mockito.any(SomeHeaderParams.class))).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

Like this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    MyCustomResponse myResponseMock = mock(MyCustomResponse.class);
    Response responseMock = mock(Response.class);
    Mockito.when(responseMock.readEntity(MyCustomResponse.class)).thenReturn(myResponseMock);

    Invocation.Builder builderMock = mock(Invocation.Builder.class);
    Mockito.when(builderMock.get()).thenReturn(responseMock);
    Mockito.when(myClientService.getHeaderParams(Mockito.any(SomeHeaderParams.class))).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, String>());
    Mockito.when(myClientService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);
    MyCustomResponse response = myControllerController.myMethod("myBusinessId", someHeaderParams);
}
```

Comment: I also have to add "Mockito.when(myClientService.buildTargetString(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("asd");" but your answer is right, thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

Using Mockito, you can configure your mocks to return anything you want, so you actually can configure a mock's method to return another mock.

Looking at the question's code, I see an important difference.

In the class MyController, the third row of the method `a()` is:

```
final Invocation.Builder builder = someService.buildRequest(targetString, someMap);
```

In the test class, seventh row of the test method, the mock is configured as follows:

```
Mockito.when(someService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);
```

So, the method used in `MyController` class is `buildRequest(String, Map)`, but the mocked method is `buildRequest(String, Map, Map)`, that is not the same method actually used by `MyController`.

It should work fine if you replace that row in your test with:

```
Mockito.when(someService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I actually had this "Mockito.when(someService.buildRequest(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap())).thenReturn(builderMock);" in my code, it was just lost by my obfuscation ;) I now edited my code in the question a bit.